# RDKit Function Issues: Python argument types in Mol.GetSubstructMatches(Mol, str) did not match C++ signature

Tags: python, chemistry, rdkit

Been programming a program to determine various functional groups from an inputted molecule. Was working great until 2 days ago. Started getting the error below. Below is a simplified exerpt of the code that generates the same error. Any suggestions on how to resovle?

```
from rdkit import Chem`
from rdkit.Chem import Draw, Descriptors, rdqueries
m= Chem.MolFromSmiles("CCCCCC")
print(m.GetSubstructMatches("[CX4]"))
```

I have checked the SMILES input and the SMARTs input for validity, created a new environment and freshly installed the rdkit library, and restarted my kernel. To no avail.

### Error

> ArgumentError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
> Cell In[2], line 4
> 2 from rdkit.Chem import Draw, Descriptors, rdqueries
> 3 m= Chem.MolFromSmiles("CCCCCC")
> 4 print(m.GetSubstructMatches(m,"[CX4]"))
>
> File ~\anaconda3\envs\ThermoSim\lib\site-packages\rdkit\Chem\Draw\IPythonConsole.py:212, in _GetSubstructMatches(mol, query, *args, **kwargs)
> 211 def _GetSubstructMatches(mol, query, *args, **kwargs):
> 212   res = mol.__GetSubstructMatches(query, *args, **kwargs)
> 213   mol.__sssAtoms = []
> 214   if highlightSubstructs:
>
> ArgumentError: Python argument types in
> Mol.GetSubstructMatches(Mol, Mol, str)
> did not match C++ signature:
> GetSubstructMatches(class RDKit::ROMol self, class RDKit::MolBundle query, struct RDKit::SubstructMatchParameters params)
> GetSubstructMatches(class RDKit::ROMol self, class RDKit::ROMol query, struct RDKit::SubstructMatchParameters params)
> GetSubstructMatches(class RDKit::ROMol self, class RDKit::MolBundle query, bool uniquify=True, bool useChirality=False, bool useQueryQueryMatches=False, unsigned int maxMatches=1000)
> GetSubstructMatches(class RDKit::ROMol self, class RDKit::ROMol query, bool uniquify=True, bool useChirality=False, bool useQueryQueryMatches=False, unsigned int maxMatches=1000)

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](https://www.rdkit.org/docs/RDKit_Book.html#smarts-support-and-extensions) `Mol.GetSubstructMatches()` is not able to transfer a string into a SMARTS-mol object. Hence you need to do this before via `Chem.MolFromSmarts()`.

```py
from rdkit import Chem
m = Chem.MolFromSmiles("CCCCCC")
print(m.GetSubstructMatches(Chem.MolFromSmarts("[CX4]")))

# output:
>>> ((0,), (1,), (2,), (3,), (4,), (5,))
```